# How to update jQuery from 1.4.4 to 1.7.1 right?

Tags: jquery, upgrade

In our project we use jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.7 now. But we want upgrade those files to versions 1.7.1 and 1.8.18 respectively. Please, give me correct algorithm for the transition.

Comment: For example, I was referring to this approach: first, to update the files from 1.4.4 to 1.5 then to 1.6, etc.
I am also interested in the important updates which are likely to affect a large number of scripts in any project, such as changing the parameters in the function delegate().
I am also interested in the various utilities and scripts that will help me to solve this problem quickly.
I understand that there is no clear algorithm for now, but I would like to know how you solve this problem, if you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the latest files from the [jQuery site](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) site, and update your `<script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags according to the updated file names.

Although you probably do not need to do many major changes to your own code, it is nice to get an overview of new features and improvements between versions. I suggest you read up on the [blog announcements](http://blog.jquery.com/) that is posted on each release, as they sum up the most important changes.

You should be especially aware of the [changes made to how attr/prop behaves release 1.6.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/). Some occurences of `attr` probably have to be changed to `prop`. Also, you should consider to change any uses of the `live`, which is now deprecated (but still working), to the new `on` method introduced in version 1.7.

It will also be a good idea to get the latest versions of other jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no 'algorithm' involved. Go and grab them from the site [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) or update your script tags with CDN links, also listed on that page.

If you need help with an upgrade path that you're having issues with, have a look at the release notes between the versions. I'm just mind-reading now.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is upload the new versions of the jQuery & jQuery UI scripts and change your `<script>` tags to include the new versions.  Your code should still work.  However, you will want to update certain deprecated functions, like replacing `.live()` and `.bind()` with `.on()`.  You can also use [jQuery Lint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/) to look for other deprecated code.  There's no algorithm, per se.

Comment: thx for jQuery Lint link